# PHP - Error when return an array from a recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

After two hours of head scratching and googling - i'm stuck!

As per the title I'm trying to return an array that is built up as the function loops through.  I want to only return the array variable on the else however it will not co-operate.  It simply returns as blank away from the function, however within the else I can print_r it and shows as expected.  It just simply won't return the array in the $open_array variable.  Any ideas (or abuse) would be greatfully appreciated!

```
function find_parent($number, $open = false) {
   if(isset($other_variable[$number])) {
        foreach($other_variable[$number] as $val) {
           $open[$val->id] = [$val->id;
           $open = find_parent([$val->id, $open);

        }
   }
   else {
    return $open;
   }
}

$open_array = find_parent($number);
print_r($open_array);
```

Comment: I don't see `$other_variable` being defined in the function's scope.

Comment: Also the `[$val->id` there isn't valid syntax. Does this even run?

Comment: What? You don't use recursion to build arrays? What planet are you from, moronia?

Comment: This does work.  When I print_r($open) I get the desired array I'm after,  it just simply won't return.  This function is stripped out to not bombard you guys with irrelevant code :).  [$val->id should be [$val->id] and $other_variable should of globaled at start of function ... sorry!

Comment: @Michael: There are perfectly valid reasons to build arrays recursively. Don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: @Michael Slip of the tongue. That's only in PHP, where arrays aren't arrays.

Comment: @Hayden What exactly are you trying to build?

Comment: @Hayden in addition to explaining the syntax errors in your comment you should update your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "then" part, you assign to $open, but then never return that value. So you can't really expect to ever get something back, except in those cases where you enter the else part, but then it's an unchanged version.

So here's what I'd do: I'd go with a version without returning $open ever.
Initialize $open before you call the function.
Pass it on.
Then modify it where necessary.

There's no reason really to return this $open value since you're passing it on by reference anyway, i.e. it should always be the same object which you're manipulating (and in those cases that it isn't, it's probably a bug).

This way, you can concentrate on the flow logic with your calls and returns, and be sure you always talk to the same datastructure.

**update**

```
function find_parent($number, $open = false) { 
   if(isset($other_variable[$number])) { 
        foreach($other_variable[$number] as $val) { 
           $open[$val->id] = [$val->id; 
           $open = find_parent([$val->id, $open); 
           return $open; // INSERTED
        } 
   } 
   else { 
    return $open; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I understand your comment thank you :).  But it still doesn't make sense to me that I can print_r($open) inside the else it prints the array as I expect it yet I can't return it?

Comment: try returning it in the "then" part as well (see update). otherwise the value is set in the "then" part, correctly passed on to the recursive call, so it's also present in the "else" part, but once the "if" part of the previous call is returned, it's not returned.